# CSS3 3D Cube not displaying correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, 3d

I just tried to use some code that creates an animated 3D cube and put a video on each side of the cube, but for some reason, some sides of the cube are always on top of the others even if they shouldn't be visible at all, especially when playing the videos.
Here is a demo btw:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqxRKQ
HTML:

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="side side1">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side2">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side3">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side4">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side5">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side6">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #FFF;
}

h2 {
  color: #FFF;
}

a {
  color: #F7E309;
}

#box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  color: #111;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.box div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -150px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -50px;
  /*    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;*/
}

.box .side1 {
  background: hsla( 0, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate1 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate1 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side2 {
  background: hsla( 60, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate2 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate2 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side3 {
  background: hsla( 120, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate3 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate3 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side4 {
  background: hsla( 180, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate4 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate4 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side5 {
  background: hsla( 240, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate5 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate5 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side6 {
  background: hsla( 300, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  animation: animate6 12s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: animate6 12s infinite linear;
}
/* for Chrome and Chrome */

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
/* for Firefox and IE10 */

@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
```

In IE 11:
[image]

In Firefox:
[image]

My question: How can I fix this?

Comment: @isherwood IE doesn't support preserve-3d or backface-visibilty, but supports basic 3-d

Comment: Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer's successor, supports `preserve-3d`.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there, there were few typos / differences between the different browser versions and I fixed these.

I've then tested the content and it runs and looks the same on:

- Chrome 43
- FF 37
- IE 11

[Watch the **demo on Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNVBBy) or run the following snippet in Full Screen to see the result:

```css
body {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #FFF;
}
h2 {
  color: #FFF;
}
a {
  color: #F7E309;
}
#box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -ms-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  color: #111;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.box div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -150px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -150px;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.box .side1 {
  background: hsla( 0, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate1 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate1 12s infinite linear;
}
.box .side2 {
  background: hsla( 60, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate2 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate2 12s infinite linear;
}
.box .side3 {
  background: hsla( 120, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate3 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate3 12s infinite linear;
}
.box .side4 {
  background: hsla( 180, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate4 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate4 12s infinite linear;
}
.box .side5 {
  background: hsla( 240, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate5 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate5 12s infinite linear;
}
.box .side6 {
  background: hsla( 300, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  animation: animate6 12s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: animate6 12s infinite linear;
}

/* for Chrome and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

/* for Firefox and IE10 */
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>IE10 preserve-3d Workaround</h2>

<div id="box">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="side side1">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side2">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side3">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side4">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side5">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="side side6">
      <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> This is the result on **IE 11.0.9600.17691** (updates **11.0.17**) on Windows 7:

Screen shots showing it running in IE11

[image]

And with some of the videos playing

[image: First Screen shot from IE11]
[image: Second Screen shot from IE11]

Comment: Even with your codepen, I still have the same issue.

Comment: I have an integrated crappy Intel HD Graphics, and the demo in the answer **is working perfectly, with and without one to six videos playing**. I've used IE 11.0.9600.17691 with updates 11.0.17. @Forivin, this is the right answer, check it out more carefully. I'm also amazed because after the comment from  Jonathan Sampson that is an IE developer I didn't think this could have been possible. Impressive job!

Comment: @AndreaLigios I have 11.0.9600.17801 (updates 11.0.19) and still, it's not working correctly. Take another look at my screenshot, it's completely bugged. Would you and anyone else who thinks this works for them, share a screenshot with me? (Make sure to play the videos while taking the screenshot.)

Comment: This makes me so dizzy.

Comment: So why the hell is that not displaying correctly on my computer? http://250kb.de/u/150529/g/mmtwg6FmmfQb.gif

Comment: Added two screen shots of cube playing the video on some faces and running on IE11

Comment: If the video render works for some people and not others then it may be down to the hardware (or drivers) being used in each system. as the 3D Rendering will get pushed to hardware if possible.

Comment: I tested it and it failed on two completely different machines (both with win 8.1 and IE 11). PC1 is a notebook with an older Ivy Bridge i7 CPU, no dedicated graphics card, 6GB RAM and an 840 Evo SSD (256GB)... PC2 is a desktop with a decent haswell i5 CPU, GTX 970, 8GB RAM and an 840 Evo SSD (128GB).

Answer (score 1):

```css
    body {
      background-color: #666;
      color: #FFF;
    }

    h2 {
      color: #FFF;
    }

    a {
      color: #F7E309;
    }

    #box {
      width: 300px;
      margin: 50px;
      -webkit-perspective: 600px;
      perspective: 600px;
    }

    .box {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      margin: 100px auto;
      position: relative;
      color: #111;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .box div {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      line-height: 300px;
      font-size: 3em;
      font-weight: bold;
      transform-origin: 50% 50% -150px;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -50px;
      -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -50px;
  /*  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;*/
}

.box .side1 {
  background: hsla( 0, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate1 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate1 12s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: animate1 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side2 {
  background: hsla( 60, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate2 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate2 12s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: animate2 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side3 {
  background: hsla( 120, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate3 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate3 12s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: animate3 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side4 {
  background: hsla( 180, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate4 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate4 12s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: animate4 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side5 {
  background: hsla( 240, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: animate5 12s infinite linear;
  animation: animate5 12s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: animate5 12s infinite linear;
}

.box .side6 {
  background: hsla( 300, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
  animation: animate6 12s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: animate6 12s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: animate6 12s infinite linear;
}
/* for Chrome and Chrome */

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
/* for Firefox and IE10 */

@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-360deg);

  }
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);

  }
}

@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
}

@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
}


@-moz-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-360deg);

  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);

  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>IE10 preserve-3d Workaround</h2>

  <div id="box">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="side side1">
        <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="side side2">
        <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="side side3">
        <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="side side4">
        <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="side side5">
        <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="side side6">
        <iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Does not render in Chrome

[image: Cube Not rendering correctly]

Comment: Same problem as in my questions. But your code doesn't even work correctly in my Firefox.

Comment: may be you use Firefox  old version so that not work in old Firefox version

Comment: I see In your image Behind the Version Tab Is Display Good So What's Problem in Output.

Comment: Dude, it's supposed to be a cube and look like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SmnvA.jpg

Comment: You can See In My Mozila Firfox  link      http://s30.postimg.org/dndy13eu9/Screenshot_from_2015_05_27_18_55_02.png

Comment: @Forvin which type of cube you create?

Comment: 6 sides, 8 corners, 12 edges

Comment: This is clearly trolling. Or madness. But I laughed so hard at this that I've *almost* voted up. EDIT: The [Title Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Stylistic_or_specialised_usage) in some comment and not in others is amazing... ok, I'm voting it up :D

Comment: this doesn't render on chrome as a cube and also doesn't render as a cube on older versions of Firefox its looks more like a 3D hash # symbol

Answer (score 0):

try to add:

`&wmode=transparent`

in iframe link

`<iframe style="display:block;" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srS7SvLV7Bg?list=PL662F41918C22319F&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`